# Reference header files from difference folders with the same relative include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a VS C++ solution with several projects.
Each project have a source folder with the same name, e.g. `utils/`:

- <Project A Root>/utils/a.h
- <Project B Root>/utils/b.h

Project C would include both `a.h` and `b.h`, so I added both A's and B's root folder to C's `Additional Include Path` configuration. Then if I have another `a.h` inside B's `utils/` folder, it will be overrided.

What's the best way to deal with such situation?

Comment: Why not create a new (static) library project that contains the "utils" part of both projects, and then use it from all the application projects?

Comment: Did you try putting all the root folders into another, super-duper-root folder, specifying only the <SuperDuperRoot> as an additional include directory, and then simply `#include <project_a/utils/a.h>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They belong to two different logical levels, so not suitable to put together.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik For the same reason, they are not suitable to mix together.

Comment: If you're asking for the "best way to deal with such situation", then the "best way" would be to reorganize the directory structure in a logical manner, so that this is no longer an issue.